# How can I filter each name in a column based on having at least one checked box on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, checkbox

Here's what I have:

Column A lists names of volunteers.

Columns B to S consist entirely of checkboxes (with column headings).

I would like to use a formula elsewhere in the spreadsheet to filter out all volunteers that are serving in at least one area (as indicated by checkboxes ie. true/false). I would prefer not to use a helper column for this. Any help much appreciated.

[Check out my sample here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl1Hc.png)

I tried using the filter function, sumif, sumproduct, nothing seems to work without getting extremely complicated or requiring a helper column.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula-

```
=FILTER(A2:A,BYROW(B2:H,LAMBDA(rw,OR(rw))))
```